# Aggregation and composition relationships between classes

Tags: c#, java, c++, c, uml

I am drawing a class diagram for the scenario below :

> Fluorescent = base, cover, switch, wiring ballast, twist, starter, mount.
>
> Incandescent = base, cover, switch, wiring socket.

But unfortunately, I am an international student who can not figure out what these stuff really are.

I know that I should draw a `SuperClass - lamp`, and both Fluorescent & Incandescent `Inherit` from Lamp. I also know that the relationship between Lamp and stuffs(like base, cover and starter etc)should be aggregation or composition, cause they are part of the Lamp.

But I have no idea which part could be shared with other Lamps (aggregation), and which part can only be own by one Lamp (composition).

Answer (score 1):

i think lamp specific `attributes like-cover,wiring socket,size etc. be a part of composition` and rest are which is common to all lamps should be in `aggregation ex-wiring ballast,switch`.

Comment: could you please tell me what's the meaning of "size" in your first sentence. @Vivek

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be slightly confused about the distinction between aggregation or composition.  If the objects have the same *lifetime* they are composite (Car = Engine+Body).  If they have have different *lifetime*, can legitimately be added or removed, (Taxi = Car + Driver) they are aggregates.  You therefore need to think about the Scope of the Problem Domain, i.e. who's perspective are you looking at this from.  The electrician vs a consumer.

Comment: @MartinSpamer.Thanks for your reminder, actually, what really confused me is that I do not know what these stuff are, if they can be translated into the language of my country, I can figure out the relationships. could you please tell me just which of these parts can be used for other lamps, rather than can just use for one lamp?

Comment: I think a  more directly way to help me figure it out is to ask: which of these parts are replaceable from the perspective of a people who use lamp? @MartinSpamer

Comment: Apart from the obvious ones, switch, wire etc I can't help with the electrical terms, try googling a glossary of Electrical terms.

Comment: Yes, who uses the abstraction, the **lamp model**.  English is my first language and I don't know what most of them are either.  One of the challenges we face as designers is learning the lanuage of the problem domain, be it accounting, retail or in this case electricians.

Comment: okay, I will ask the question you might happy be asked. Besides the **generalization** relationship between LAMP <--- Fluorescent &  LAMP <--- Incandescent and the **aggregation** or **composition** association between the electrical elements and LAMP. what hierarchies relationships should also be observed as a designer? @MartinSpamer

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by 'hierarchies relationships', however inheritent is synomonous with Generalisation.